# Is there a standard way of playing longer sound clips?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm currently using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID)` to play sound clips.  My understanding is that this can only be used to play clips under 30 seconds.

What is the standard way of playing longer sound clips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)